# Is there any option to call the C# DLL from ReactJS for Desktop Application?

Tags: reactjs, windows, electron, desktop

I would like to use the ReactJS for front end. And back end is C# library. Without using any API (like ASP .net) I need to access the C# library.

I am using electron JS to build the Desktop application. Is there any possibility from electron also fine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.